# Importing Spring tutorial guide results with NoUsableDaemonFoundException on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have [downloaded](http://spring.io/tools) SPRING TOOL SUITE (3.6.1.RELEASE for Linux) and I am trying to go through [REST tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/), but I am unable to import it to STS. Since tutorial is using Gradle, I had installed Gradle IDE Extension from STS' Dashboard. I used the Dashboard for importing tutorial project and it resulted with NoUsableDaemonFoundException.

[image]

I also tried to import the tutorial to STS as Gradle project, but it resulted with similar problem:

[image]

I tried this on freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 as well and got the same problem.

EDIT:
Everything works fine with STS installed on Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: You still can check it out from github and import it as Gradle project.

Comment: @Ikrnac I did. That's the second screenshot.

Comment: ok sorry missed that. Another option is to try Maven version.

Comment: I don't think there is Maven version. There are other guides built with Maven, but all 3 tutorials (tutorials are longer then guides) are Gradle projects.

Comment: oh I see, I though all this Spring stuff is buildable with Maven and Gradle. Didn't try tutorials so far.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a side-effect of https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3922 that is basically a problem in Eclipse 4.4 update.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue is Eclipse version specific, so I agree with Radim. You probably have updated to Eclipse 4.4.1. Try getting the latest Gradle Eclipse tooling from this update site: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly It may resolve the problem for you.